# javascript: mouse hover for background coloring and opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousehover

since yesterday i started javascript to make a hovering effect that applys to the body of the page(i want to change the background color of the body of the page while hovering a div),

I've watched some tutorials and i tried it myself but i ended up failing, I would like to know how can create this effect with javascript , i used something like this.

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("body").style.backgroundColor = "black"
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("body").style.backgroundColor = "white"
}
```

```css
.college .image {
  left: 100px;
  top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college:hover .imagefirst {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.college .imagesecond {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-110px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(-110px, -500px);
}

.college:hover>body {
  background-color: black
}

.lycee .image {
  left: 700px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  width: 537px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: translate(-160px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(-160px, -325px);
}

.formations .image {
  left: 1250px;
  top: 510px;
  position: absolute;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-100px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(-173px, -600px);
}

body {
  background: url("accueil.png") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white/* rgb(0,85,170); */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseover="mouseover()" onmouseout="mouseout()" class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

i cannot use jQuery ortherwise i wouldn't have tried to ask this question in the first place , i need to know how can i apply the hover effect in a JS file into my html and css page

-edit-

i've been taught how i can use mouse hovering and background coloring but i would like to ask another thing, it is about opacity, i want to put opacity on the orther divs i decided to do the same thing at what i was taught before `document.lycee.style.opacity = "0.1";` and `document.formations.style.opacity = "0.1";` but it actually don't work, as for `document.body.style.opacity = "0.1";` , It changes the opacity on the whole page. can you help mee for one last time please?

Comment: Try using document.getElementsByTagName(body); instead of classname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your Javascript code loads after the content and replace `onmouseOver` with `onmouseover`.

Instead of 
`document.getElementsByClassName("body").style.backgroundColor = "black"`
you can do this
`document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

if you want to play with th e DIV's

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.opacity = "0.8";
}
```

if you want to change the styles only of specific element with className

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('classNameHere');
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.opacity = "0.8";
}
```

Edited!

Comment: how do i know if the javascript code loads after the content? should i just move     `<script src="scripts/javascriptpp.js"></script>` at the end of my html?

Comment: This is one of the ways another way is to use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ //.. do something here after content loaded });`

Comment: i've changed `document.getElementsByClassName("body").style.backgroundColor = "black"` by `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`and it actually worked, when i mouse hover the color changes and when i mouse hover out of the div it change the color to what i've choosed . it worked! but may i ask something else? right now i've tried to put opacity on the orther divs so i've made  `document.body.style.opacity = "0.1"` but then it  puts the whole page at 10% so i've tried `document.getElementsByClass("lycee").style.opacity = "0.1";` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: thank you Yordan , you helped mee alot about using javascript !

Comment: if you want to select the first element within a class, just use querySelector: `document.querySelector("classNameHere")`

Answer (score 2):

Body is not a class so this statement will not work, `document.getElementsByClassName("body").style.backgroundColor = "black"`

To Select Body you can use `document.body` or `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
}
```

```css
.college .image {
  left: 100px;
  top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college:hover .imagefirst {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.college .imagesecond {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-110px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(-110px, -500px);
}

.college:hover>body {
  background-color: black
}

.lycee .image {
  left: 700px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  width: 537px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: translate(-160px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(-160px, -325px);
}

.formations .image {
  left: 1250px;
  top: 510px;
  position: absolute;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-100px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(-173px, -600px);
}

body {
  background: url("accueil.png") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white/* rgb(0,85,170); */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseOver="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"
}
```

```css
.college{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.college .image {
  left: 100px;
  top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}

.college:hover .imagefirst {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.college .imagesecond {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-110px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(-110px, -500px);
}

.college:hover>body {
  background-color: black
}

.lycee .image {
  left: 700px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  width: 537px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: translate(-160px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(-160px, -325px);
}

.formations .image {
  left: 1250px;
  top: 510px;
  position: absolute;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-100px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(-173px, -600px);
}

body {
  background: url("accueil.png") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white/* rgb(0,85,170); */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseover="mouseOver();" onmouseout="mouseOut();" class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

good going! but small mistake of uppercase and lowercase letters

1)

```
please see your function name carefully 
<div onmouseover="mouseover()" onmouseout="mouseout()" class="college">

'O' should be capital as you defined it mouseOver() and mouseOut();
```

2)

```
for using byName you must have tag with that name so for using 
document.getElementsByClassName("body").style.backgroundColor = "black";
add name="body" in <body>  
for example <body name="body">
```

or

```
  simply use byTagName atribute like this
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

happy coding, :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a Tag using `getElementsByClassName` which is looking for class, so either use `getElementsByTagName` as in the snippet below or add `class="body"` to body tag

```js
function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
.college .image {
  left: 100px;
  top: 475px;
  position: absolute
}
.college{
border:1px solid black;
height: 50px;
width:50px;
}
.college:hover .imagefirst {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.college .imagesecond {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-110px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.college:hover>.imagesecond {
  transform: translate(-110px, -500px);
}

.college:hover>body {
  background-color: black
}

.lycee .image {
  left: 700px;
  top: 500px;
  position: absolute
}

.lycee .imagefourth {
  width: 537px;
  height: 600px;
  transform: translate(-160px, 500px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lycee:hover>.imagefourth {
  transform: translate(-160px, -325px);
}

.formations .image {
  left: 1250px;
  top: 510px;
  position: absolute;
}

.formations .imagesixth {
  width: 550px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: translate(-100px, 400px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0.2s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.formations:hover>.imagesixth {
  transform: translate(-173px, -600px);
}

body {
  background: url("accueil.png") 33em 0% fixed no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white/* rgb(0,85,170); */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

  <title> sainte marie </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="saintemarie">
    <a href="college/collegesaintemarie.html">
      <div onmouseOver="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" class="college">
        <img class="image imagefirst" src="http://via.placeholder.com/196x175" />
        <img class="image imagesecond" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="lycee/lyceesaintemarie.html">
      <div class="lycee">
        <img class="image imagethird" src="http://via.placeholder.com/183x140" />
        <img class="image imagefourth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="c&formation/c&fsaintemarie.html">
      <div class="formations">
        <img class="image imagefifth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/172x153" />
        <img class="image imagesixth" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x440" />
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```